# Get error when I called RedirectToAction in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Environment.

**Develop :** VisualStudio2012 MVC4 .NetFrameWrok4.5
**Server :** WindowsServer2008 R2 iis 7.5

If i failed log in. I call -> `return RedirectToAction("LoginError", "Search");`
It is working successfully when i debug on VisualStudio.
But, It is return error page on server.

This is error message.

> Server Error in '/' Application
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException:
>   System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) +479
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__17()
>   +33    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +263
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +230
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +20    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +20
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +20
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +453    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371

I found this.
[RedirectToAction Causes "No route in the route table matches the supplied values" in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504255/redirecttoaction-causes-no-route-in-the-route-table-matches-the-supplied-values)

`return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" });`

But I can't understand mean of new `{ area = "AreaName" }`. 
I didn't know what is this.

please teach me about this if you know. Thank you.

Comment: post your code. describe where you get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
Reason of the problem is Routeconfig.cs.
I wrote only this.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SearchPart_three_para",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{requestcode}/{systemid}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Search",
                action = "SearchPart",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                requestcode = UrlParameter.Optional,
                systemid = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

And i edited like this.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SearchPart",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Search",
                action = "SearchPart"
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SearchPart_three_para",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{requestcode}/{systemid}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Search",
                action = "SearchPart",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                requestcode = UrlParameter.Optional,
                systemid = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

reference here. 
[ASP.NET MVC : Empty ActionLinks appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911471/asp-net-mvc-empty-actionlinks-appearing)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have defined Areas you will have no need for that. To get an idea what the areas are check this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx).

In short they are like a separate part of your MVC application.

Regarding your error I would assume that using this overload `return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName")` should be enough but without seeing the code it is just an assumption.

Also check the full list of overload for redirect to action in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx).